# What is a Arquillian Resource?

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian

What is the use case of @ArquillianResource? Can I inject arbitrary objects in? Do they need to be registered under CDI?

ie

```
@ArquillianResource
URI uri
```

Answer (score 3):

The `@ArquillianResource` annotation JavaDoc gives a good overview

> Arquillian has support for multiple injection points like @EJB,
>   @Resources and @Inject, but there are also non standard component
>   model objects available within the Arquillian runtime that can be of
>   useful during testing.
>
> Arquillian can expose these objects to the test case using the
>   @ArquillianResource injection annotation.

Look into the [arquillian-extension-producer GitHub repository](https://github.com/MatousJobanek/arquillian-extension-producer), which gives examples of implementing CDI-like behavior in Arquillian by using `ArquillianResource` or `TestEnricher`.

One of typical usecases for `ArquillianResource` is when you want to inject your custom type. Then the steps are following:

1. implement `ResourceProvider` which says which types is able to provide and how to create/find the provided instances - [sample here](https://github.com/MatousJobanek/arquillian-extension-producer/blob/master/arquillian-extension-producer/src/main/java/arquillian/extension/producer/provider/ProviderProducer.java)
2. register the provider in a new Arquillian extension - [sample here](https://github.com/MatousJobanek/arquillian-extension-producer/blob/master/arquillian-extension-producer/src/main/java/arquillian/extension/producer/RegisterExtension.java)
3. register the new Arquillian extension by using service loader - `LoadableExtension` SPI - [sample here](https://github.com/MatousJobanek/arquillian-extension-producer/blob/master/arquillian-extension-producer/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.LoadableExtension)